# Hiding sender information in HTTP when using Java

Tags: java, http, wireshark

I was playing around with the HTTP POST and GET requests in Java. I was just trying to mimic the requests that my browser sends using Java (I am using the URLConnection class). However, when I used Wireshark to analyze the packets that my browser sent and the ones that were sent through Java, I found a big difference:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8OvR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPBPR.png

(open links to view the images)

When I send HTTP POST/GET, the tool that I am using (either a browser or Java) sends information about itself. However, I want to send EXACTLY the same packet through Java as I would through a browser. Is there a way to do it? How can I hide the sender (in this case Java) information? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529682/setting-user-agent-of-a-java-urlconnection

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but the only good answer on the other page is at the bottom.

`setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");` see the JDocs for [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

You can also use this for any of the other headers such as `Accept-Language`. Be careful if you set the `Accept-Encoding` as that may cause the server to gzip something which Java will not handle correctly and you will need to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818468/how-to-check-if-inputstream-is-gzipped).

I am not sure why the are suggesting to set a system property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send *exactly* the same packets using pure Java, well, you can't.

But this library might help: http://www.savarese.com/software/rocksaw/